# How do i solve the error "No such file or directory" error when building with Dockerfile

Tags: docker, .net-core, dockerfile, docker-build

I have a dockerfile in my .net core project directory, I published my project into an `out` directory within my project directory, the `out` folder has all my dlls, but when i try to run the command `docker build -t floormindcore.web .` I get this error

```
stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder154411130/out: no such file or directory
```

This is my Dockerfile below

[image]

**Folder structure of project**

The `out` directory is in the project directory on my linux server, and so is my `Dockerfile`, and this is where i run the docker build command from. The `out` directory contains my published dlls

[image]

Comment: Your work dir is different from your add directory

Comment: @vegiops I have updated my workdir, see image, i still get the same issue

Comment: Use copy instead of add put workdir above the copy step

Comment: How does you directory structure look like?

Comment: Make sure where you are building the file. The out directory actually exists. Also try replacing `out/` in your file by `./out` (shouldn't matter as such). But still check. Move the `WORKDIR` before `ADD`. As mentioned replace ADD by `COPY`. If still doesn't work add a `RUN mkdir /FloormindCore` before the `COPY` command

Comment: @TarunLalwani I have tried all of that, i have actually updated what my file looks like now, see image above please.

Comment: @vegiops I have done that and updated the image, still getting the same issue

Comment: seems like your out directory is not in the current directory, can you give the full path

Comment: @vegiops I have added the folder structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the issue is because there is a .dockerignore file in here which has "*" in it... this was probably added when i created the docker support through visual studio, so i just renamed the file and it seems to build successfully now.